# How do I animate an element inside the collectionview in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I want to bind the rotate animation on an element which is inside the collectionview, if there is a way to animate it with only xaml then it wouldn't be the problem but in Xamarin.form we have to reference the object then animate it with C# like this `await lable.RotateTo (360, 2000);`. How do I do the same to an object which is inside the collectionview creating dynamically.

Here the example code, I want to rotate `iconize:IconLabel` (Just a Label with an icon)

```xml
<CollectionView x:Name="MyCollectionView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
                SelectionMode="Single">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <iconize:IconLabel
                    WidthRequest="46"
                    Text="far-sync"
                    FontSize="26"
                    TextColor="{StaticResource Key=AccentColor}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

There is also a Bindable `Rotate` property on `Label` should I use that instead?

P.S: It would be very easy if somehow `iconize:IconLabel` can be binded to a property in `MyCollection` then I would loop through all the elements and bind the animation to it.

Comment: Have you tried binding the Rotate property ?

Comment: @Cfun No not yet, was thinking that is it the good idea to bind it then animate it continuously with loop would it have the performance hit

Answer (score 0):

Like @Cfun said, `Rotate` property would work for you. But please note that, the Rotation property would roate once when you load the app. If you wanna more for this, you still need do something in the code behind.

```
 <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Rotation="250"
            Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```